# How to set a RpostgreSQL query as a dataframe object for RpivotTable?

Tags: r, shiny, rpostgresql, rpivottable

I am trying to use RpostgreSQL to source data to be fed into the rpivotTable package and displayed to the user using shiny.

Error: data should be a data.frame, data.table, or table

Unfortunately I am new to R and I am unable to work out how to set my postgreSQL query to be set as a dataframe, table or data.table so that a rpivotTable can be created.

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(rjson)
library(pool)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(rpivotTable)


ui <- fluidPage(


##DEBUGGING##

tableOutput("tbl"),

rpivotTable(Titanic),

### sql & rpivottable attempts ###

rpivotTable("OverallPivot"),

rpivotTableOutput("tbl2"),


output$pivtbl2 <- renderRpivotTable(rpivotTable(data = DataSet,
                                                aggregatorName = "Sum",
                                                vals = "Count",
                                                cols = "order_date",
                                                rows = "product_id",
                                                menuLimit = 1200,
                                                rendererName = "Line Chart"))

)


server <- function(input, output, session) {


  ###DEBUGGING SERVER

  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    conn <- dbConnect(
      drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
      dbname = "store",
      host = "localhost",
      user = "postgres",
      password = "123456")
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
    dbGetQuery(conn, paste0(
      "SELECT * FROM orders;"))
  })

  ###Attempted sql & rpivotTable attempts SERVER

  OverallPivot <- renderRpivotTable({    conn <- dbConnect(
    drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
    dbname = "store",
    host = "localhost",
    user = "postgres",
    password = "123456")
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
  dbGetQuery(conn, paste0(
    "SELECT * FROM orders;"))
  })

  DataSet <- renderRpivotTable({    conn <- dbConnect(
    drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
    dbname = "store",
    host = "localhost",
    user = "postgres",
    password = "123456")
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
  dbGetQuery(conn, paste0(
    "SELECT * FROM orders;"))
  })


tbl2 <- renderRpivotTable({
  conn <- dbConnect(
    drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
    dbname = "store",
    host = "localhost",
    user = "postgres",
    password = "123456")
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
  dbGetQuery(conn, paste0(
    "SELECT * FROM orders;"))
})

  }


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am able to display the table from postgres sql in the "tbl" format in shiny and a pivottable using the Titanic dataframe in R in shiny.

I just can not work out how to combine the two together and use the postgres sql query to display an rpivottable in shiny.

I`ve split my successful examples in the DEBUGGING section and my weak failed attempts

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the R object outside of the `renderRpivotTable` function.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)
library(RPostgreSQL)

function(input, output, session) {

  conn <- dbConnect(
    drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL"),
    dbname = "store",
    host = "localhost",
    user = "postgres",
    password = "123456")

  on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)

  db_data <- dbGetQuery(conn, paste0("SELECT * FROM orders;"))

  output$pivot <- renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(data = db_data)

  })

}
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)

test_page <- fluidPage(
  rpivotTableOutput('pivot')
)

test_page
```